# Getting Undefined Index error (Magento)

Tags: magento

I am getting an undefined index error on HTTP_ACCEPT for some reason. I'm not sure why.

This is the line of code it's happening on:

```
if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] is used to get the header of the current request if available. So you have to slightly change the condition statements. use this one

```
if ((in_array('HTTP_ACCEPT', $_SERVER) && strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) { }
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late comment. So far so good. I don't seem to be getting the Warning anymore in the log. I will let you know if it holds.